# Inconsistent value with Perl records

Tags: arrays, perl

I made a Perl script to deal with structured data. Array elements are created like this in a loop by incrementing `$idxrep` (`@filelist` is different at each loop) :

```
$directory[$idxrep]{"size"}=$repsize;
$directory[$idxrep]{"numberoffiles"}=@filelist;
$directory[$idxrep]{"listoffiles"}=\@filelist;
```

When I check the content of the array with :

```
print (Dumper $directory[2]{"size"});
print (Dumper $directory[2]{"numberoffiles"});
print (Dumper $directory[2]{"listoffiles"});

print (Dumper $directory[5]{"size"});
print (Dumper $directory[5]{"numberoffiles"});
print (Dumper $directory[5]{"listoffiles"});

...
```

I have the correct sizes, the correct amounts of files but incorrect lists of files (contained in `{"listoffiles"}`) while it's based on the same array `@filelist`

I already used `$DataList[3]=\@filelist;` to assign a whole array but here, it seems to be different and incorrect.

**Do you know where the mistake is?**

Comment: When you say the lists are "incorrect", what exactly is wrong with them? And are you sure that the problem is in the very few lines you've shown us? Perhaps you could create a [minimal example that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your array `@filelist` is declared outside the loop, so you are putting a reference to the same array into multiple places in the data structure.

You can either move the declaration inside the loop, so that you pick up a new array each time, ot you can *copy* the array into an anonymous array when you set up the data element, like this

```
$directory[$idxrep]{"listoffiles"} = [ @filelist ];
```

Note that there is no need to keep track of `$idxrep` as you can simply `push` a new hash onto the array each time, like this

```
my %dir = (
  size          => $repsize,
  numberoffiles => scalar @filelist,
  listoffiles   => [ @filelist ],
);
push @directory, \%dir;
```

but note that, once again, `%dir` must be declared within your loop